# I want to use a progress bar with RxJava like you can with AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask, rx-java, progressdialog

I want to replace my AsyncTask with RxJava in android.  My current AsyncTask goes like this:

```
public class ProgressBarAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void> { 

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        ringProgressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(context,"MyProgressBarTitle","Working please wait",true, false);                  
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... void) { 
       //do work
       myTask();
       return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void void) {
        super.onPostExecute();
        ringProgressDialog.dismiss();
    }
}
```

Here's my RxJava replacement:

```
    public static Observable<Void> getObservable(final Context context,final String... params) {

       return Observable.defer(new Func0<Observable<Void>>() {
          @Override
          public Observable<Void> call() {
             return Observable.just(myTask());
          }
       });

   }

    public static Subscriber<Void> getSubscriber() {
    Subscriber<Void> subscriber = new Subscriber<Void>() {
        @Override
        public void onCompleted() {
           ringProgressDialog.dismiss();

        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Throwable e) {
            Log.d(TAG,e.toString());

        }

        @Override
        public void onNext(Void aVoid) {
             manipulateData();

        }
    };
    return subscriber;
}
```

My Activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity { 
   private ProgressDialog ringProgressDialog;

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      GetNumberObservable.Observable()
                       .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                       .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()))
                       .subscribe(getSubscriber());
   }
}
```

How do I mimic the onPreExecute() method in the AsyncTask where I kick off the progressDialog?

Comment: Use doOnNext() method

Comment: @Tuby How do you do that?

Comment: lookup this class https://github.com/TwistedEquations/android-rxmvp-tutorial/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/twistedeqations/rxmvp/sample/activities/home/mvp/HomePresenter.java, it uses doOnNext to set showLoading to true, which enables progress bar, you could call ringProgressDialog.show() in this method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- In RxJava you have the [do](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/do.html) operators, that creates `Observable`
  lifecycle events listeners, in your case you want to do something
  (update the UI) before the task started, which mean you want the
  `doOnSubscribe` event. (side note it is true with 'cold'  Observables
  that started thier work when subscrbied to - like your case)   Just
  beware to call `.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()))` before
  the `doOnSubscribe` in order to get notified on the mainThread, as
  you're updating the UI.
- Instead of using both `defer` and `just`

  ```
  return Observable.defer(new Func0<Observable<Void>>() {
       @Override
       public Observable<Void> call() {
          return Observable.just(myTask());
       }
    });
  ```

  you can use `fromCallable`:

  ```
      Observable.fromCallable(new Callable<Object>() {
         @Override
         public Object call() throws Exception {
             return myTask();
         }
     })
  ```

Answer (score 5):

Here is how I would do it:

```
public final class ProgressOrResult<T> {
    final int progress;
    final T result;
    public ProgressOrResult(int progress, T result) {
        this.progress = progress;
        this.result = result;
    }
}

ProgressDialog ringProgressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(
    context, "MyProgressBarTitle", "Working please wait", true, false);                  


Observable.fromEmitter((Emitter<ProgressOrResult> emitter) -> {
    // generate "progress"
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
        sum += i;
        emitter.onNext(new ProgressOrResult(i, null));
        Thread.sleep(1);
    }
    // generate "result"
    emitter.onNext(new ProgressOrResult(100, sum));
    emitter.onComplete();

}, BackpressureMode.BUFFER)
.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
.subscribe(result -> {
    if (pr.result == null) {
        ringProgressDialog.setProgress(pr.progress);
    } else {
        ringProgressDialog.dismiss();        

        // process the result here
    }
}, error -> {
    // handle error here
})
```

Answer (score 1):

I am showing `progressBar` in`doOnSubscribe()` , hiding in `doOnError()` and in `subscribe()`.

Please refer to [this](https://medium.com/@ValCanBuild/making-rxjava-code-tidier-with-doonsubscribe-and-dofinally-3748f223d32d) link for more details.

Answer (score 0):

<sub>Shameless Promotion</sub>

I've created [RxLoading library](https://github.com/ndori/RxLoading) for that, it can do this and much more,

you can just do something like this:

```
networkCall().compose(RxLoading.<>create(loadingLayout)).subscribe(...);
```

it consists out of 2 classes, a custom view (loadingLayout) and RxLoading which is a [transformer](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/Implementing-Your-Own-Operators#transformational-operators) that glue it all together, you can choose to work with both or either of them.
if you want RxLoading with a simple progress bar you just need to implement an interface and you are done.

you can check more on the [GitHub page](https://github.com/ndori/RxLoading).